# Specifying generic type information through a parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have this code I am refactoring:

```
    if (response != null) {
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<GameInfo>>() {}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return (List<GameInfo>) gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
    }
```

Can I create a function where the "List" part could be any Collection type?

Example of illegal code:

```
private <T> T collectionFromJson(String pResponseJson, Class<T> pCollectionClass) {
    T result = null;
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<pCollectionClass>() {
    }.getType();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Example of illegal call to illegal code that illustrates what I'm shooting for:

```
return collectionFromJson(response, List<GameInfo>.class);
```

Comment: your question is very related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111899/how-do-i-build-a-java-type-object-at-runtime-from-a-generic-type-definition-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to be possible using a `Class<T>` argument, since `Class` only supports representing raw types like `List` - the type `List<GameInfo>` cannot be represented by a `Class` object, which is why `TypeToken` exists.

Your method would need to take a `TypeToken<T>` argument instead and leave it up to the caller to create that argument:

```
private <T extends Collection<U>, U> T collectionFromJson(String pResponseJson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    return (T)new Gson().fromJson(pResponseJson, typeToken.getType());
}

...

TypeToken<List<GameInfo>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<GameInfo>>() { };
List<GameInfo> lst = collectionFromJson(response, typeToken);
```

(disclaimer: I only have experience with Java/generics, not GSON)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I'll give it a shot. The GSON part is superfluous to the question.

Comment: It would be more general to take a `Type` parameter, which you can pass directly to `fromJson()`. The caller could then pass a `Class`, or pass the result of `typeToken.getType()`, or pass a `Type` generated some other way, depending on what it wants

Comment: @newacct - That's true, but wouldn't it then lose the compile time type safety afforded by `TypeToken`?