# How to get type of generic interface in java

Tags: java, gson

I have a class Bucket which is passed as a generic type in the Comparator interface. I am working with GSON to register a type adapter for this type.

The typeadapter function has the signature

```
public GsonBuilder registerTypeAdapter(Type type, Object typeAdapter)
```

I want to pass the first argument as the type object

```
java.util.Comparator<org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.Terms$Bucket>
```

I tried `Comparator<Terms.Bucket>.class` which throws me a syntax error . What is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: You need to pass the `type` object as a parameter. Not a `.class `

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111899/how-do-i-build-a-java-type-object-at-runtime-from-a-generic-type-definition-and

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only used for compile time safety, then they are erased (they don't exist at runtime). So writing something like this `Comparator<Terms.Bucket>.class` isnt possible. You need to create a explicit class:

```
public class BucketComparator implements Comparator<Terms.Bucket>
{
    ...
}
```

After this you are able to pass the type as follows: `BucketComparator.class`