# Is it impossible to instantiate a parameterized type through reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Let's suppose you're writing a library, and it is to act upon a client class that is passed to it (i.e. client code cannot be changed).

```
class ClientClass {
    public GenericClientClass<AnotherClientClass>  someField;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is instantiate someField through reflection. Something like:

```
class LibraryClass{
    public instantiateAllFields(Object obj){
        //iterate through all fields of obj.class, and instantiate them
    }
}
```

The only requirement of the client's fields is that a constructor without arguments exists. (e.g. GenericClientClass() {} )

The purpose of this is to create a highly automated testing library, currently for my own purposes.

I've been able to implement the above for almost all cases (arrays, objects, primitives, generic arrays etc.);  however, this particular case has stumped me.

field.getType().newInstance() does not work, since the generic type parameters are removed.

field.getGenericType() doesn't work, because it returns a type, not a class.

**If** It's a known generic class, I can create a special case to deal with it. For example:

```
            Class<?> genClass = ((Class<?>)((ParameterizedType)field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            JArray jArray = new JArray(true,n,genClass);
            field.set(object, jArray);
```

...I'm guessing I could do this for things like ArrayList, HashMap etc.

However, I would like to cover the general case, and be able to instantiate any generic class (with a single parameter, and a zero-argument constructor) that may be passed into the library.

Any ideas?

Note that the type of the generic parameter **is known**. I can get at it through field.getGenericType().

Comment: Related: [How do I build a Java type object at runtime from a generic type definition and runtime type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111899/how-do-i-build-a-java-type-object-at-runtime-from-a-generic-type-definition-and)

Comment: There's no such thing as "an instance of a parameterized type"; or, rather, there's no difference between instances of parameterized types with different type parameters. The type parameter is just something the compiler uses to enforce type correctness. If you're instantiating it at runtime, the compiler is not in the loop. So you just have to create a "raw"/"wildcard"-typed instance, and cast it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "an instance of a parameterized type"; or, rather, there's no difference between instances of parameterized types with different type parameters. The type parameter is just something the compiler uses to enforce type correctness.

If you're instantiating it at runtime, the compiler is not in the loop. So you just have to create a "raw"/"wildcard"-typed instance, and cast it; and you have to own the problem of ensuring that the cast actually is safe.

Assuming `GenericClientClass` is not abstract, and has a constructor without parameters:

```
someField = (GenericClientClass<AnotherClientClass>) GenericClientClass.class.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

and deal with the resulting unchecked cast warning appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely helpful. 

However, is there a way to cast through reflection?


I can't  use the code `(GenericClientClass<AnotherClientClass>)` because these classes are defined in the client, not in the library.

Comment: No. Casting is also (mostly) just a compile-time thing: it's just the way of telling the compiler that it needs to trust you know more type information than it does. The reflection API is largely ignorant of generics.

Comment: I see - makes sense. 

The issue I then have is that the `GenericClientClass.class.getConstructor().newInstance()` instance has lost the information about its parameter type, so when I then attempt to recursively instantiate its own fields, I get plain Objects instead of the specified type. 

...I suppose I can pass the type of the parameter down through the recursive call explicitly, and then use this to correctly instantiate the deeper fields. Should do the job.

Thanks again :)